# How can I append a unique identifier onto rows with same column value

Tags: sql, powershell, unique, identifier

It's hard to explain my question, but here is the issue. I have a table of 350k records. The table is filled with skus and other part information. There are many rows that have the same sku. For example there are 5 rows with the sku 45666. I need to put a unique identifier on each of these. e.g 45666~1, 45666~2, etc... The solution I've come up with was using a while loop in a while loop and just doing them one at a time like this

```
$i=0
while($i -le $array.length) {
$j=0
$mfp = $array.itemnumber[$i]
while($array.itemnumber[$i] = $mfp) {
    Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query "update whiproducts set number = $j"
    $i++
    $j++
}
```

}

What I would do after this is concat number with the sku when I select it. The problem here is this has been running for like 30 minutes which just won't work well with the way I'm going about this project. Is there some quick and easy way to do this I'm missing!?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like you are running 350k different queries to update each row.  Is that right?  If so that is your problem.

Comment: You're right I am. I don't know what else to do!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this query a try (please don't run this on production data before testing or backing up):

```
update t
set t.sku = t.sku + '~' + cast(t.RowNumber as varchar)
from (
    select sku, row_number() over(partition by sku order by sku) as RowNumber
    from whiproducts) t
```

Comment: This should work.  And it seems to edit the sku field exactly how @Patrick Mahoney asked it to be edited. +1

Comment: I'm getting an error near the last parenthesis and near cast(t.rownumber as varchar) Incorrect syntax

Comment: @PatrickMahoney - I forgot the table alias (the `t` at the very end) try that and see what happens.

Comment: ok great this works! It's just a little weird. They are starting off at like 40 sometimes and 180 any ideas why?

Comment: @PatrickMahoney There is no reason I can think of that that should be the case. How are you determining that it starts at 40? I think I would have to see your query to get a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

How about appending on a unique GUID.  Then you can just do things with a single update statement, no looping at all.

`UPDATE whipproducts
SET number = number + '_' + cast(NEWID() as varchar(100))`

Answer (score 0):

If you're bringing your data down to a local datatable or something, you can change your source query to:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sku) AS ID, *
FROM YourTable;
```

Then you can pretend "ID" is your unique identifier when working with the data, though it won't help much if you have to send the data back to the server.

Really, there should be some kind of primary key on the table already.  If not, you may want to consider adding one if you have the privs to do so (`ALTER TABLE`).